# Using jwt-go Library - Key is invalid or invalid type

Tags: parsing, go, jwt, token, jwt-go

I am trying to pass in a token to the "Parse(token String, keyFunc Keyfunc)" GO routine defined in this GO-library (http://godoc.org/github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go)  for JWT-token parsing/validation.

When I pass the token to this function -

```
token, err := jwt.Parse(getToken, func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
        return config.Config.Key, nil
    })
```

I get an error which says "Key is invalid or invalid type".

My config struct looks like this in config.go file  -

```
config struct {
 Key string
}
```

Any suggestions to solve this problem? The token I am passing is a JWT token.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
config struct {
 Key string
}
```

`Key` needs to be a `[]byte`

Comment: While this code sample may possibly answer the question, it would be preferable to include some essential explanation to your answer. As it stands now this answer adds little to no value for future readers.

Comment: How to implement this exactly? Earlier I tried using []byte("key") without any struct and it gave me the error. A little elaboration to the solution might be helpful for newcomers @Jesse

Answer (score 16):

I am not sure if this can be an issue for someone else.

My problem was I was using Signing Method `"SigningMethodES256"` but `"SigningMethodHS256"` or Any with `SigningMethodHS*` works fine.

If someone knows why this is an issue please answer.

Comment: A bit late. It's because each signing method has its own key type. You can see the type expected for every signing method here https://golang-jwt.github.io/jwt/usage/signing_methods/

Comment: Yes thanks, but few people getting this issue.

Answer (score 6):

Other way is to do something like this -

```
token, err := jwt.Parse(getToken, func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
        return []byte(config.Config.Key), nil
    })
```

The whole idea being that the Parse function returns a slice of bytes.

Answer (score 3):

This is working for me.

> token.SignedString([]byte("mysecretkey"))

```
func GenerateJWT(email string, username string) (tokenString string, err error) {

    expirationTime := time.Now().Add(1 * time.Hour)
    claims := &JWTClime{
        Email:    email,
        Username: username,
        StandardClaims: jwt.StandardClaims{
            ExpiresAt: expirationTime.Unix(),
        },
    }

    token := jwt.NewWithClaims(jwt.SigningMethodHS256, claims)
    tokenString, err = token.SignedString([]byte("mysecretkey"))

    return
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking a look at the function signatures in the [GoDoc for github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go](https://godoc.org/github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go#Parse) we see:

```
func Parse(tokenString string, keyFunc Keyfunc) (*Token, error)

type Keyfunc func(*Token) (interface{}, error)
```

`Keyfunc` requires you to return `(interface{}, error)`. Given the mysterious `interface{}` type, you might expect to be fine returning a `string`; however, a peek under the hood reveals that `Parse()` tries to `Verify()`, which attempts the following type assertion with your `interface{}` value as the `key`:

```
keyBytes, ok := key.([]byte)
```

That will succeed for `[]byte` types, but will fail for `string` types. When that fails, the result is the error message you are getting. Read more about [type assertions in the Effective Go documentation](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interface_conversions) to learn why it fails.

Example: https://play.golang.org/p/9KKNFLLQrm

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var a interface{}
    var b interface{}

    a = []byte("hello")
    b = "hello"

    key, ok := a.([]byte)
    if !ok {
        fmt.Println("a is an invalid type")
    } else {
        fmt.Println(key)
    }

    key, ok = b.([]byte)
    if !ok {
        fmt.Println("b is an invalid type")
    } else {
        fmt.Println(key)
    }
}
```

---

```
[104 101 108 108 111]
b is an invalid type
```